# How do I make a Modal Dialog Box Auto Open after 2 seconds?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

How would I make this Auto Open after 2 seconds?
I am using Jquery Modal Dialog box. I am using jquery, classic asp, and Internet Explorer

```
$(function() {
  $("#dialog-message").dialog({
    title: "OTHER PARTICIPANTS ALERT",
    dialogClass: "alert",
    modal: false,
    center: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: '600px',
    minheight: '600px',
    show: 'fade',
    autoOption: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
  $(" #dialog-message").each(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).dialog("open");
    }, 2000)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from some syntax errors, it looks like the problem is the scoping of `this`.

Inside the `setTimeout` scope, `this` doesn't refer to the element. You need to capture a reference to `this` outside of the function:

[**Working Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wdo1yLus/)

```
$("#dialog-message").each(function() {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(self).dialog("open");
  }, 2000);
});
```

Since you are selecting an element by its `id`, you could really just simply the code to the following:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
}, 2000);
```